# mortgage deadline

Tags: monopoly

Playing this game in different languages and in different groups of people I've met strange rule "after 3 rounds property goes from mortgage back to bank". 
Aslo they had strange price to buy back from mortgage with original price instead of usual half price +10%.

Please tell me what is written about it in official rules?
The last one, an I make actions not in my turn? for example I started game 1, we have 4 players, and now is 3rd player turn to make a move and I want to buyback two cards from mortgage, is it allowed?

Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really ask your questions one at a time, in separate questions.

**Do mortgages go to the bank after three rounds?**

No. The rules say nothing about this. When your friends bring up a rule you have never heard of, ask them to point to the rule in the rules booklet. If you lost yours, print a new one from [here](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf).

**How much does it cost to buy back mortgages?**

The amount of the mortgage plus 10% interest. A $70 mortgages costs $77 to lift. From the rules:

> In order to lift the mortgage, the owner must pay the Bank the
>   amount of the mortgage plus 10% interest.

**Can I take actions when it is not my turn?**

The rules are unclear on this. Some sources say you can conduct your business whenever you want:

- [This blog](http://mospaw.com/monopoly/commonly-missed-monopoly-rules/13/information)
- [This answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/6476/6692) makes a good point about what the electronic versions of the game allow or disallow
- [The top answer on this Yahoo Answers question](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091020170525AA55ZFS)

Other sources say you can only conduct most business on your turn:

- [This answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/6566/6692)
- [This article](http://boardgames.about.com/od/monopolyfaq/f/buy_houses.htm)

One action most that people agree on is that you cannot buy houses immediately after a dice roll (*"Hah! You rolled a 6! I'm going to upgrade that spot before you land on it!"*). Also, some business must occur when it is not your turn. For example, you may be required to mortgage a property or sell houses in order to pay a debt. We will categorize this as "necessary business".

That leaves unnecessary business. Unnecessary business would include pretty much any action that you take when you are not in danger of going bankrupt. For example, buying a house, unmortgaging a property, or trading. You and the other players should make it clear when these types of actions are allowed before the game starts.

Comment: I have always seen it played where the only action you can take out of turn is to trade with the active player. Any actions such as building houses or un-mortgaging property had to be done on your turn.